Importance of Environment in System-Observer Entanglement and Decoherence
It has been stated in places such as Sean Carroll's talks that including the environment in our description of a quantum measurement process is important in understanding why we do not "feel like" we're in a superposition:
$$\left(\alpha|\text{A}\rangle + \beta|\text{B}\rangle\right) |\text{environment}\rangle |\text{observer}\rangle$$
$$\rightarrow \left(\alpha|\text{A}\rangle |\text{environment of A}\rangle + \beta|\text{B}\rangle |\text{environment of B}\rangle\right) |\text{observer}\rangle$$
$$\rightarrow \alpha|\text{A}\rangle |\text{environment of A}\rangle |\text{observer of A}\rangle + \beta|\text{B}\rangle |\text{environment of B}\rangle |\text{observer of B}\rangle$$
However, I don't really understand the problem with the initial picture in which we don't worry about the environment:
$$\left(\alpha|\text{A}\rangle + \beta|\text{B}\rangle\right) |\text{observer}\rangle$$
$$\rightarrow \alpha|\text{A}\rangle |\text{observer of A}\rangle + \beta|\text{B}\rangle |\text{observer of B}\rangle$$
Why would this scenario allow us to "feel like" we're in a superposition any more or less than when we take the environment into account? If it is simply that the Hilbert space of the environment is so huge that recoherence is incredibly unlikely, isn't the Hilbert space of the observer alone already extremely large?

The issue is why you don't see interference between different outcomes after you do a measurement. If you imagine that you have a system $S$ and measurement device $M$ that interact so you get the state:
$$(\alpha|A\rangle_S+\beta|B\rangle_S)|0\rangle_M\to\alpha|A\rangle_S|A\rangle_M+\beta|B\rangle_S|B\rangle_M$$
A measurement device could in principle be another coherent quantum system, in which case it wouldn't be too difficult to undo this measurement. For example, you could have a photon in an interferometer and introduce a Faraday rotator on one arm to rotate the photon's polarisation by $\pi/2$ radians so the polarisation would depend on what arm of the interferometer the photon is in. This is effectively a measurement of the photon's direction into its polarisation. It would be possible to undo this measurement by introducing a further Faraday rotator into that arm to rotate the photon back to its original polarisation.
Another issue is that you could imagine measuring the joint $S,M$ system in some other basis such as
$$\tfrac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(|A\rangle_S|A\rangle_M+|B\rangle_S|B\rangle_M)\\
\tfrac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(|A\rangle_S|A\rangle_M-|B\rangle_S|B\rangle_M)\\
\tfrac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(|A\rangle_S|B\rangle_M+|B\rangle_S|A\rangle_M)\\
\tfrac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(|A\rangle_S|B\rangle_M-|B\rangle_S|A\rangle_M)$$
There has to be some explanation of why you regard the $|A\rangle_S|A\rangle_M,|A\rangle_S|B\rangle_M,|B\rangle_S|A\rangle_M,|B\rangle_S|B\rangle_M$ as the relevant basis for the states of $S,M$.
When the measurement result has spread into the environment you can no longer control what happens to it and whatever set of observables is monitored by the environment is going to be the set that fixes what relative states are available. Information about a measurement result can only be copied indefinitely often if it is in some particular orthogonal set of states, see Section II of:
https://arxiv.org/abs/0707.2832
The indefinite copying of information is what fixes the set of possible relative states. So interaction with the environment fixes the set of possible relative states. Also, if you can see a measurement result it has already spread into the environment because that happens a lot faster than the time required for your brain to process seeing a measurement result. And in any case typically you will observe a measurement result from the enrvironment not by directly coupling to a measurement device, e.g. - you will look at photons reflected from a computer screen with the measurement result on it.
